# Check all items in listview that are checked or uncheck

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have checkbox and listview with checkboxes, if I have to check all items in listview the checkbox is true or checked

[image: sample picture 1]

else if not all items are check in listview then the checkbox is false or unchecked

[image: sample picture 2]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask].

Comment: Please post what you have tried... we help with specific problems and or issues, not write it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [ItemChecked()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.itemchecked(v=vs.110).aspx) event of the ListView, which fires whenever a ListViewItem is checked or unchecked, then simply compare the `.Count` of the [ListView.CheckedItems()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.checkeditems(v=vs.110).aspx) collection with the `.Count` of the [ListView.Items()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.items(v=vs.110).aspx) collection:

```
Private Sub ListView1_ItemChecked(sender As Object, e As ItemCheckedEventArgs) Handles ListView1.ItemChecked
    CheckBox1.Checked = (ListView1.CheckedItems.Count = ListView1.Items.Count)
End Sub
```

This will make CheckBox1 checked if **all** items in ListView1 are checked, otherwise it will be unChecked.